# Netbeans & Java - using getResource() - returning null

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, javax.imageio

I am trying to load a background to my JFrame using the following code:

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));
```

where for `s`  I have tried:

```
/res/Background/bg_menu.gif
Background/bg_menu.gif
/Background/bg_menu.gif
res/Background/bg_menu.gif
```

My res folder is in the project root like so:

```
Game
-- src
-- res
```

I have done the following:

```
Project Properties -> Sources -> Add Folder -> res
```

The error I'm getting returned is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
at com.game.rpg.tilemap.Background.<init>(Background.java:29)
at com.game.rpg.gamestate.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:34)
```

Comment: In res, do you have a `Background` folder with a file called `bg_menu.gif`?

Comment: Where is your class located? The path has to be w.r.t class. Else use 

getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( /res/..) and /res should be in classpath

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I have these files.

Comment: @Optional My classes are located in com.game.rpg.* . I also tried your other method but this does also return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your package structure

```
/res/Background/bg_menu.gif
```

and `/res` is a source folder, then

```
/Background/bg_menu.gif
```

should be at the root of your classpath. As such, you can access it with

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Background/bg_menu.gif"));
```

Note the leading `/`. [The rules for the path are explained in the javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

If this doesn't work, then your application is not being built correctly with Netbeans. check the deployment.

Comment: Thanks for some reason it doensn't give me the error anymore, although now I'm just getting a black rectangle where the image should've loaded. Is that a mistake somewhere else in my code?