# Reading a json file in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

So I am having troubles with reading a Json file in Java.

It is a Json file with content in this format:

```
{
  "_id": 2864071,
  "name": "Neustadt",
  "country": "DE",
  "coord": {
    "lon": 12.56667,
    "lat": 52.400002
  }
}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
package controllers;


@Named(value = "cityID")
@SessionScoped
public class getCityIDs implements Serializable {



    public long getCityIDs(String name) {

        //Read the json file

        try {

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);

            // get a number from the JSON object

            String travelName = (String) jsonObject.get("name");

            if(travelName.equals(name)){
                long id =  (long) jsonObject.get("_id");
                System.out.println(id);
                return id;
            } else {
                System.out.println("else");
                return 0;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getCityIDs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getCityIDs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("einde functie");
        return 0;
        // JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(getClass().getResource("/json/city.list.json").toString());
    }

    public String test(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

However, it gives me an error at this line:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
```

being:

```
Severe: Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 88.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at controllers.getCityIDs.getCityIDs(getCityIDs.java:45)
```

For some reason it can't read the filepath? "Unknown source"?
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The method just returns a "0" when I call the method in another class, with as country name "Neustadt".
Basically all I want is for this function to return the ID for a certain city.
The names are stored in the Json, together with the ID.

**Edit:**
Ideally I want to be able to parse the JSON file, which is located inside the project.
I tried using .getClass().getResource("/path/to/json"); but that didn't work at all.

**EDIT: FIXED**

```
package controllers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

@Named(value = "cityID")
@SessionScoped
public class getCityIDs implements Serializable{



    JSONObject jsonObject;
    public long getCityIDs(String name) {

        try { 

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dataSteden/stedenNamen1.json");

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
            String line;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(line);
               }
            }

            String travelName = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println("stad: " +travelName);
            System.out.println("testttt");
            if(travelName.equals(name)){
                long id =  (long) jsonObject.get("_id");
                System.out.println(id);
                return id;
            } else {
                System.out.println("else");
                return 5;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getCityIDs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getCityIDs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("einde functie");
        return 0;
        // JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(getClass().getResource("/json/city.list.json").toString());
    }

    public String test(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unknown source means you do have have the source code for the simpleJSON library. Also, try to stick with Java variable naming conventions. Your class should not be called `getCityIds`. The method can be, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the first line

Comment: Don't worry about it. The Java stacktrace is trying to give you line numbers and file names for the JSON library that you are using, and it can't. That is what "Unknown source" means in that output. Regarding the actual error, you have shown valid JSON, so I don't understand why you are getting that error.

Comment: Are you sure you have shown the contents of the file in the code here? `city.list.json` sounds like it should be a JSONArray, not a JSONObject

Comment: This is the json I'm using: http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/

Comment: I think that could indeed be the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is line-delimited

```
{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}
```

Therefore, you cannot throw the entire file into a `JSONParser`, you must read the file line-by-line and parse each line as a `JSONObject`, from which you can extract out the needed key-values.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Now I am wondering, the file is situated in my project.
I don't want to call it locally on my computer since there's more people working on this project. But I can't seem to do it. Ideally I want something like this :    FileReader reader = new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("/json/city.list.json"));

Comment: Right. As long as you have that file located in some json folder in the root of the src/ folder of the project, I think what you have there should work

Comment: I put it under Source Packages, and call it like this :

FileReader reader = new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("/json/city.list").toString());

But its giving me a nullpointerexception, it works when calling it locally now, calling it line by line

Comment: It's been a while since I've needed to read a resource like that. I know there are many question about it here on StackOverflow, though. For example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161395/netbeans-java-using-getresource-returning-null

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for everything!

Editted my response to how it should be

Comment: Well, "should be" that your class name is capitalized and more descriptive to its purpose than a single method, but that's a separate problem :)

Comment: True, Ill take care of that!