# Converting/Deserializing a JSON with an ArrayList of ArrayList without a Key

Tags: java, arrays, json, json-deserialization, pojo

I have a json file with multiple arrays. It is not clear to me how to set up Key-Value pairs when this isn't one given.  I understand that a [ … ] represents an array and { … } represents an object. I looked at tutorials online but none had an answer to my question and what I found in this JSON.

The Problem:
I'm trying to convert every property in the JSON to POJO / dataTypes. There are these properties in the arraylist below that don't have a key-value pair. "5", "1964-07-20", null, "7", null, Within this arraylist there are properties that have a key-value pair. { "retail": "7.05", "price": "12.07", "cost": "3.01", "fees": "1.75", "profit": "5.85" } How to create a class that handles both and stores each property to a datatype.
It will have the same fields at the start (the 5 none key properties), It will always be the same. The Value is what only changes.

Thanks in advance.

There is no Key-Value associated with the below properties

```
  "5",
  "1964-07-20",
  null,
  "7",
  null,
```

Below are my two classes that I attempted to create and the original JSON file. Also an auto-generated JSON.

Music.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Music {
    private String artist;
    private String record;
    ArrayList<MusicRecords> musicRecords = new ArrayList<MusicRecords>();


    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getRecord() {
        return record;
    }

    public ArrayList<MusicRecords> getMusicRecords() {
        return musicRecords;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public void setRecord(String record) {
        this.record = record;
    }

    public void setMusicRecords(ArrayList<MusicRecords> musicRecords) {
        this.musicRecords = musicRecords;
    }
}
```

MusicRecords.java

```
public class MusicRecords {

    private double retail;
    private double price;
    private double cost;
    private double fees;
    private double profit;


    public double getRetail() {
        return retail;
    }

    public void setRetail(double retail) {
        this.retail = retail;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public double getFees() {
        return fees;
    }

    public void setFees(double fees) {
        this.fees = fees;
    }

    public double getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }

    public void setProfit(double profit) {
        this.profit = profit;
    }
}
```

Music.json

```
{
  "artist": "Beatles",
  "record": "Something New",
  "musicRecords": [
    [
      "5",
      "1964-07-20",
      null,
      "7",
      null,
      {
        "retail": "7.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "3.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "5.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "8.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "5.05",
        "price": "10.07",
        "cost": "2.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "4.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "9.05",
        "price": "14.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
      }
    ],
    [
      null,
      "1967-05-17",
      "4",
      null,
      2,
      {
        "retail": "7.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "3.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "5.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "8.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "5.05",
        "price": "10.07",
        "cost": "2.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "4.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "9.05",
        "price": "14.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Below is the auto-generated JSON Formatter. It doesn't create key-value pairs for the inner arrays shown below. It creates an ArrayList of type Object.

```
        "retail": "8.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
```

JSON Auto Formatted File

```
public class Application {
  private String artist;
  private String record;
  ArrayList<Object> musicRecords = new ArrayList<Object>();


 // Getter Methods 

  public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
  }

  public String getRecord() {
    return record;
  }

 // Setter Methods 

  public void setArtist( String artist ) {
    this.artist = artist;
  }

  public void setRecord( String record ) {
    this.record = record;
  }
}
```

Finally, these are the websites that I visited to find an answer but couldn't.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816746/reading-a-json-file-in-java
http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html#parsing-json-into-java-objects

I also used these auto generators below:
https://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php
http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-java.html
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have a specific part of the code that isn't working or throwing an exception? I am struggling to see where your actual problem comes from!

Comment: Thanks for your Welcome @Henry Twist. I'm. trying to convert every property in the JSON to POJO. There are these properties in the arraylist below that don't have a key-value pair. 
 "5",
  "1964-07-20",
  null,
  "7",
  null,

Within this arraylist there are properties that have a key-value pair.
{
        "retail": "7.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "3.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "5.85"
      }

How to create a class that handles both and stores each property to a datatype.

Comment: Oh I see! Is the JSON response  always guaranteed to have those fields at the start? Also what JSON library are you thinking of using?

Comment: It will have these fields at the start, It will always be the same. The Value is what only changes. I'm using GSON. This is for a JAva Cloud Application. The number of the inner arrays might vary,  but that shouldn't make a difference. 

{
        "retail": "7.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "3.01",
        "fees": "1.75",
        "profit": "5.85"
      },
      {
        "retail": "8.05",
        "price": "12.07",
        "cost": "5.01",
        "fees": "3.75",
        "profit": "7.85"
      },

Comment: Please do NOT give any further information in **comments**. Always **edit** your question and update it. Everything required to understand the problem should sit IN the question.

Comment: Consider checking the following https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Comment: Great to know. Thanks @GhostCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here seems to lie with your JSON format. It starts off fine with the `artist`, `record` etc. but then you have defined an array of `musicRecords` which seems to not only represent an array of records but also some extra data as well (a date `"1964-07-20"` for example).

Without knowing what this structure is for, it would seem like those fields belong with the `artist` and `record` fields in your root JSON object, where they need some sort of key to represent their purpose.

Then you could easily make a POJO that makes a bit more logical sense and will be easier to use in your project.

---

However if the JSON file is coming from an external source that you have no influence over, you have two options:

**Use the *JSON Auto Formatted File* that you posted**

This approach is probably not the best idea, mostly due to the POJO then not representing a logical object that will be easy to use in your code but also because of type safety. You have to upcast all of the objects in your list to `Object` which would mean casting them all back down again when they need to be accessed. This is generally bad practice and if the JSON structure changed at all this would be very difficult to debug.

**Use a different JSON library**

The best solution would be to use a JSON library that allows you to read a JSON file step by step and then map to a POJO that you're comfortable with and better represents your use case. However as far as I am aware, GSON is a direct deserialization library so cannot offer the fine tuning you would need to map to a different format.

Comment: Just wanted to add that it may be useful to add "why" you feel that " it doesn't seem very logical or very safe to read". I have an idea why you're mentioning this (probably related to the fact that there are multiple value-types in the array right now) but I'm making an educated guess.

Comment: You're right, edited my answer to hopefully provide a better explanation.

Comment: Hi @HenryTwist,

Thank you for your response. I agree with it. I ended up asking the group that created the JSON to update it accordingly.